# Definir una variable global para usarla en varias vistas independiente del controlador de cada vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, laravel-blade

Necesito declarar una variable globlal, algo similar a:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Estoy consumiendo un API y necesito lograr que en formulario de login se cree la variable `$user` a modo global para usarla en toda la app. No estoy muy familiarizado con este tema según vi se hace algo como `Laravel/passport`, pero no se si hay otro método para lograrlo.

En resumidas cuentas lo que necesito es: Al hacer login, usar la variable de retorno `$user` a nivel global.

¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Lo solucionaste con la respuesta publicada o aún no?

Comment: aun no, estoy rebajando en eso.

Comment: No lo logro aun, replanteo mi pregunta acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92736/cómo-pasar-la-variable-user-a-ser-variable-global-para-usarla-en-todas-las-vis

Answer (score 2):

Añade en tu `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` el usuario autenticado a todas las vistas que sean cargadas.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function($view) {
            $view->with('user', Auth::user());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero no estoy usando passport, ¿se pede hace del mismo modo pasando la variable al provider desde un controlador?

Comment: Replanteo pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92736/cómo-pasar-la-variable-user-a-ser-variable-global-para-usarla-en-todas-las-vis