# ¿Cómo pasar la variable $user a ser variable global para usarla en todas las vistas?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller

Tengo el siguiente controlador del cual necesito que los datos de usuario estén disponibles a nivel global.   ¿como puedo lograrlo?

```
 public function login(Request $request){

        $client = new Client();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'min:3|max:100', 
        ]);

        $response = $client->post("http://localhost:8000/v1/login", [

            'headers' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
                'json' => [
                    'email' => $request['email'],
                    'password' => $request['password'],
                ]
        ]);

        $user = json_decode( $response->getBody()->getContents() );

        return view('pages.home', compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas, los métodos del controlador sólo retornan una vista. Me parece que lo que buscas realizar es una sesión: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Estuve leyendo al respecto de lo que dices y parece que es lo que necesito, voy aprobarlo y te cuento.

Comment: mira esta por favor: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92899/problemas-con-laravel-session

Answer (score 2):

lo que queres hacer es simple, tenes que generar un helper y listo.

1- Creá un archivo que se llame por ej helpers.php
2- en composer.json agregalo en la parte de autoload. Quedaría algo así.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

3- en consola hacé composer dump-autoload
4- En el archivo helpers.php poné lo siguiente

```
<?php
// Helper de todos los usuarios por ejemplo
function users()
{
    return App\User::all();
}
// Helper de usuario autenticado (Logueado)
function authUser()
{
    return \Auth::user();
}
```

5- Despues de esto podes usar los helpers en cualquier lugar haciento users() o authUser() funciona como cualquier otro helper de laravel solo que lo escribis vos.
Igualmente también podes hacer un \Auth::user() en cualquier lugar y obtenes los datos del usuario autenticado
Espero haber entendido lo que necesitabas y que te sea de utilidad mi respuesta
Saludos
Maru

Answer (score 0):

Se puede realizar, utilizando variables de sesión.

Un ejemplo de como agregar una variable a la sesión en un controlador, es el siguiente (donde el primer parámetro, es el nombre que va a tener la variable de sesión, mientras que el segundo parámetro, es el valor):

```
    Session::put('idUser', $idUser);
```

También, se puede agregar un array de datos:

```
    Session::put('client', $client);
```

Luego, por ejemplo, en una vista se puede consultar si esta definida tal variable, y realizar alguna acción:

```
        @if( Session::has('idUser') )
```

Y también, por ejemplo, en otro controlador, se puede recuperar el valor de dicha variable, de la siguiente manera:

```
        $idUser = Session::get('idUser');
```

Existen varias funciones de Laravel, para el manejo de variables de sesión.
Para más información, adjunto el siguiente link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Nota importante: al agregar o consultar variables de sesión dentro de los controladores, es importante definir la librería para su uso:

```
use Session;
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Laravel tiene un helper para tu caso

```
auth()->user() --> retorna el modelo completo del usuario
auth()->user()->id --> retorna el id del usuario logeado
```

si lo quieres usar en las vistas

```
{{auth()->user()}}
```