# Laravel Session Return: Null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, session, laravel-blade

Necesito pasar variable se session para obtener variables en otras vistas o controladores al final obtengo un `NULL`

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $client = new Client();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'min:3|max:100', 
    ]);

    $response = $client->post("http://localhost:8000/v1/login", [

        'headers' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
            'json' => [
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => $request['password'],
            ]
    ]);

    $user = Session::put('response', $response);

    dd($user);
}
```

En pantalla el resultado es Null

En mi otro controlador no obtengo nada en la vista:

```
public function index(){

    $user = Session::get('response');

    return view('pages.home', compact('user'));
}
```

¿Cual es la forma correcta de obtener estas variables en otros controladores y vistas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto que el resultado de `Session::put()` sea NULL, la explicación la encuentras en su código:

```
/**
 * Put a key / value pair or array of key / value pairs in the session.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $key
 * @param  mixed       $value
 * @return void
 */
public function put($key, $value = null)
{
    if (! is_array($key)) {
        $key = [$key => $value];
    }

    foreach ($key as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
        Arr::set($this->attributes, $arrayKey, $arrayValue);
    }
}
```

---

En cuanto a la sintaxis para poner y tomar datos de la sesión, **es correcta también**, tal vez no estás recibiendo ninguna información al hacer el llamado al API o estás intentando imprimir la variable de forma incorrecta en la vista.